# Realiza un programa que solicite a un usuario un número de día de la semana y diga si es fin de semana o es laboral

Tags: java, condiciones

tengo un ejercicio de JAVA que me pide que compruebe si los días de la semana son laborales o son de fin de semana. Asignando un número a cada día de la semana, es decir, Lunes es igual a 1, Martes es igual a 2... así hasta 7 que es el Domingo. El código que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;

        System.out.println("Dime un número correspondiente 
        a los 
        días de la semana:\nLunes = 1\nMartes = 2\nMiércoles = 
        3\nJueves = 4\nViernes = 5\nSábado = 6\nDomingo = 7");
        num = sn.nextInt();

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) {
           System.out.println("Es día laboral.");
        } else if (num <= 7) {
           System.out.println("Es fin de semana.");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Pasa que no contempla que el usuario meta un número menor que 1. Si pones un 0 por ejemplo pone que es fin de semana y ahora mismo no encuentro como arreglarlo.

Comment: El 0 entrará en la condición del `else if` porque estás contemplando solamente que sea menor a 7. Por lo qué, necesitarás cambiarlo para que contemple 6 o 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega la condición faltante `if (num > 5  && num <= 7)`:

```
if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) {
   System.out.println("Es día laboral.");
} else if (num > 5 && num <= 7) {
   System.out.println("Es fin de semana.");
} else {
   System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por una de las soluciones! Ahora lo he visto, estaba hecho un lio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar si ingresa el valor **0**:

```
if(num == 0){
   System.out.println("Debe ingresar un número superior a 0");
} else if (num > 0 && num <= 5) {
   System.out.println("Es día laboral.");
} else if (num > 5 && num < 8) {
   System.out.println("Es fin de semana.");
} else {
   System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme a comprenderlo !